# My dog ate a chicken bone 2 years ago

Tags: dogs

I might be a little bit paranoid about this, but I can't forget the time when my dog once ate a chicken bone. It happened 2 years ago, and I didn't know that it was dangerous so I gave it to him. There were no symptoms of chocking or discomfort in him. He was normal as usual. Already 2 years have passed, but I am still worried. Is it sure that he is totally fine?

But I'm still not sure if 'that' incident has affected him or not. And because of it, I am not sure if he is okay or if he has stomach pains until now. He seems normal.

Another concern is that he only consumes 1.5 cups to 2 cups of dry dog food and drinks about 2 cups of water a day. Is this normal? If it's not, is it because of that past incident?

What if he is still bleeding internally or having pains and I don't know it? I don't see any abnormalities in his daily life, but we never know....they can't tell us :(

I'm just really worried....the memory of 2years ago haunts me :(

*

Some info about my dog:

Breed : Korean Jindo

Age : 2 years and 7 months old

Gender: Male

Weight : 15 kg

Comment: I feel you should discuss this with the vet. If he's bleeding internally, we couldn't tell.

Answer (score 4):

If nothing has happened in the 2 years since he's eaten that bone, it's certainly fine by now. If there had been internal haemorrhage, it would've shown itself long ago. And the bone itself, or a fragment of it, wouldn't have stayed in your dog's system for that long -- even if it had stuck somewhere, it would've dissolved by now. It's organic matter, and it doesn't 'live' that long. So, worst case scenario, it could have left a wound on your dog's intestines, and those scarred which could result in something, possible irritation or worsening vermicular movement or I don't know, anything. But that's worst case scenario. If your dog was fine initially after eating that bone (no discomfort, no black stools [intestinal haemorrhage], nothing else to indicate anything wrong), he's fine. Sure, bones *can* be dangerous, but there's no 100% guarantee that they'll hurt your dog (or cat, or any other pet). I don't encourage anyone to feed their pets bones, but it's not a tragedy.

So, to the second part of your question, no, it can't be because of that incident. I'm not sure about the norms for dogs (I have cats) and the exact dog food you're using (norms differ for different brands), but generally if he eats at least 2/3 of the amount proposed by the food manufacturer and doesn't lose weight/muscle, and generally feels fine, it's within norm. But if you're really worried, talk to a vet.

Also, dogs are much worse at hiding pain/discomfort than cats, so if you know your dog well enough, and you're observant enough, generally you should notice when something's wrong. It's not *always* the case, but when something's seriously wrong, usually there are signs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It really helped :) I probably don't have to worry about it...since there is no sign of unusualities

Comment: @Angee You're welcome :) Yeah, you probably shouldn't in this case, but it's a good thing to watch your pet closely. I have an elderly cat with several chronic conditions, and being paranoid helps :))